# SQL script to update all column values starting with number and - with blank in Postgresql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, sql-update

I need to update a varchar column's values
The values start with a number followed by - and then some letters

For Ex: `27-Check This`

I need to update  this value ie, I need to remove the starting number and the `-`

Expected output Example: `Check This`

NB: only the starting number and `-` should be removed all the values after the first alphabet should not be changed. Ie, if some number or `-` is present after the first alphabet then that should not be removed.

For ex: `27-Check 23-C This`

Expected output: `Check 23-C This`

NB: I am new to sql so please help even if this looks simple to you

Comment: `regexp_replace`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe can you pls help me with the regex that will be used here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `regexp_replace` to remove the leading digits:

```
update the_table
   set the_column = regexp_replace(the_column, '^[0-9]{1,}\s*-\s*', '')
where the_column ~ '^[0-9]{1,}'
```

`^[0-9]{1,}-` in details:

- `^` match at the start of the string
- `[0-9]{1,}` at least one number
- `\s*` followed by zero or more (white) space
- `-` followed by a dash
- `\s*` followed by zero or more (white) space

The `where` clause ensure that only those columns are changed that need to be changed (e.g. values not starting with a number won't be touched at all).

Comment: Thanks what is there is a space after the number Ex : 27  - check . How to update these kind of values ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want everything after the first hyphen when the pattern starts with a number, you can use:

```
update t
    set col = substring(col from '-(.*)')
    where col ~ '^[0-9]+-';
```

`substring()` with a pattern is a nice implementation of what would be called `regexp_substr()` in other databases.  It simply returns the first time the pattern is in the string.  The full pattern is matched, but if there are parentheses, then only that portion is returned.